# Is there any function in SQL Server to convert a number into Time format?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, time, format, numbers

I am getting a whole number for the duration of product. For example : 62, 103, 184, 4543. I want to convert it in time format. Let say , in case of 62, it would format like '00:01:02'. I am looking for a function which can resolve my problem. Is there any function in SQL Server which convert a number into time format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @d datetime
Set @d = Convert(datetime, '20010101',112 )

Set @d = dateadd(s, 62, @d)  --add 62 seconds to base date

Select convert(varchar,@D,108)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have two choices. You can do the division by 60 yourself like so:

```
SELECT  RIGHT('0' + CAST(@seconds / 3600 AS varchar), 2) + ':' +
        RIGHT('0' + CAST((@seconds / 60) % 60 AS varchar), 2) + ':' +
        RIGHT('0' + CAST(@seconds % 60 AS varchar), 2)
```

Or you can do some sort of datetime-related kludge:

```
SELECT  CONVERT(varchar,
                DATEADD(second, @seconds, CAST('1-Jan-2000' AS datetime)),
                8)
```

Format 8 is hh:mi:ss from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).